# Is there anything wrong in running multiple schedulers within a webapp?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I'm using spring's scheduling and I want to have separate schedulers, one for short running tasks and another for long running tasks.

**The main reasons for this:**

- In this context, the short running tasks are more mission critical than the long running tasks (short running tasks have to execute every minute, long running once an hour)
- If I configured single threaded mode, the long running tasks will block the short running tasks.
- If I configured the thread pool size incorrectly, the long running tasks could potentially block the short running tasks.

Is there *anything wrong with splitting the tasks* into separate schedulers like this or is the convention to *always use a single scheduler within an app* and bump up the pool size?

I'm not aware of any scheduling/task-splitting patterns so any assistance there would be great. I would want this question to ignore that there are potentially alternative frameworks for this (like spring batch maybe). I'm more interested in the design choice and why it might be incorrect.

Comment: what version of quartz you are using?

Comment: @SumeetSharma I was thinking of quartz in conjunction with Spring, but I opted to use spring's native scheduling.

Comment: i find working with quartz lot easier hence i suggested it that way.. I personally feel you can easily edit the configuration when you directly use quartz.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you to configure two separated task using Spring scheduled methods.

```
@Async
@Scheduled(cron = "your cron expresion")
public void task1(){

}

@Async
@Scheduled(cron = "your cron expresion")
public void task2(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Quartz 2.0,you can have multiple (non-clustered) scheduler instances use the same set of Quartz tables, so long has they have `unique instance names`. So you can simply `configure separate thread pool sizes` and assign the critical jobs to one scheduler and not so critical to other one. Also there are SCHED_NAME columns in all the quartz tables so the jobs can be easily segregated using the scheduler instance names.

*I think this seems legitimate as the reason you pointed out very correctly that long running task could potentially block the threadpool for short running tasks.*

Answer (score 0):

You CAN configure multiple schedulers.BUT, you should (& you must) consider setting the proper thread pool. We've got a similar case where few task runs every hour, and then few runs every night. Setting the proper corePoolSize, and maxPoolSize is the key to success with multiple job schedulting.Alongwith that you always have possibility to configure queueCapacity to save the day when thread limit reached.